# Android Studio 3.x: Emulator very slow (especially rendering)

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I've got a problem on my Dell Inspiron 7000 Gaming (i7-7700HQ, 16GB RAM, Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 Ti, Windows 10) and self-build desktop pc (i5-3350P, 16GB RAM, AMD Radeon HD 7870, Windows 10) regarding the Android Emulator (current Android SDK and Android Studio version). Intel VT-X is enabled.
No matter which API version and device I choose, the emulator is always very slow and you can watch the views getting rendered step by step. You can trace this behaviour in Logcat as well.

What I've tried so far:

- reinstalling Intel HAXM (with different values for the allocated memory)
- reinstalling Android Emulator
- running the emulator with GPU0 (Intel) or GPU1 (Nvidia)
- changing OpenGL ES Renderer to different values
- restarting my machines
- reinstalling Android Studio and Android SDK
- searching Google and Stack Overflow

Is anyone out there who had the same problem and maybe can provide a solution?

My Dell PC is very slow in general (mouse is stuttering when applications like Firefox are opened, Adobe applications like Illustrator are very slow) after updating Windows 10 to the currently supported version (support for the Dell image ended in October 2017). The issue exists on my desktop PC as well so I don't think that it's conditioned by the Dell setup. I'm happy about possible solutions for this problem as well. ;-)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: added Dell AS SSD benchmark.
[image: Dell AS SSD benchmark]

EDIT: added AVD configuration

```
Name: Pixel_2_API_26

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Johannes\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_26.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 26)

Skin: 1080x1920

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_2

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

skin.path.backup: _no_skin

image.androidVersion.api: 26

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: no

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Pixel_2_API_26

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 420

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 API 26

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:bc5032b2a871da511332401af3ac6bb0

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Can you screenshot the image you use for emulator? Normally, if you are using Windows, recommend to use x86 image, instead of arm64 or armeabi

Comment: See the details of my AVD above. Is this information sufficient?

Comment: the AVD will not affected, as the Ram /space will be auto increase depend on your usage. Mostly is the SDK image you are using. I believe you are using API 26, so the choose ABI = x86, like this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#systemimagepage

Comment: @Jacky sorry, I don't get your point. I'm using an x86 image at the moment running API level 26 (see above). What should I change now?

Comment: use API 25 and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Have you got SSD hard disk ? if so, test it

Comment: A Samsung 850 EVO (250 GB, SATA III) is used for my desktop PC and a Toshiba NVMe SSD (512 GB) for my Dell laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alternative emulator? I used the built-in emulator also initially and it loads terribly slow (I use AMD by the way, so no VT-X). Then I changed to Nox, it's far better, only take seconds to install apk.

Answer (score 0):

From SDK 26 and above, android emulators have been very slow. Google hasn't done anything about this.
**USE AN EMULATOR RUNNING SDK 25 OR BELOW AND NOTICE THE SIGNIFICANT DIFFERENCE**

Comment: Thanks. However, this will block me to test my apps with every API version though